# SQL server management from visual studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2005

I need to make some permission changes on a MS SQL server (2005) database.  Some tables read only for all but dbo, some tables read-write for all etc.  In the past I used the management program that came on the SQL server disk.  That is not an option for me right now.  I cannot find a place in visual studio to alter table permissions.  Does visual studio have that feature?

Comment: I do not have the disk handy and I was unaware of the SQL Server Management Studio Express free download.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you download [SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en)?

Answer (score 3):

GRANT for tables:

```
GRANT <permission> [ ,...n ] ON 
    [ OBJECT :: ][ schema_name ]. object_name [ ( column [ ,...n ] ) ]
    TO <database_principal> [ ,...n ] 
    [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]
    [ AS <database_principal> ]

<permission> ::=
    ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] | permission [ ( column [ ,...n ] ) ]

<database_principal> ::= 
        Database_user 
    | Database_role 
    | Application_role 
    | Database_user_mapped_to_Windows_User 
    | Database_user_mapped_to_Windows_Group 
    | Database_user_mapped_to_certificate 
    | Database_user_mapped_to_asymmetric_key 
    | Database_user_with_no_login
```

example:

```
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.YourTable TO YourUser
GRANT INSERT ON dbo.YourTable TO YourUser
GRANT DELETE ON dbo.YourTable TO YourUser
```

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2008 does not have this ability and I don't see it included in the future editions either.

Answer (score 0):

you could always use the command line to alter the permissions.